# If Akroan Horse is put into play attacking, does it get removed from combat by its own ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I came across this interaction when thinking about a horse tribal.

[Shadowfax, Lord of Horses](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shadowfax%2C%20Lord%20of%20Horses) has this ability:

> Whenever Shadowfax, Lord of Horses attacks, you may put a creature card with lesser power from your hand onto the battlefield, tapped **and attacking**.

[Akroan Horse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Akroan%20Horse) has this ability:

> When Akroan Horse enters the battlefield, an opponent gains control of it.

How do these two abilities interact? In a two player game, it seems that Akroan Horse would be an attacking creature, but also that the defending player would have control over it. Is there a rule which removes it from combat when its controller changes?

Comment: [Related](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/25028/30400)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a rule that removed creatures from combat when its controller changes.

> 506.4. **A permanent is removed from combat** if it leaves the battlefield, **if its controller changes**, if it phases out, if an effect specifically removes it from combat, if it’s a planeswalker that’s being attacked and stops being a planeswalker, if it’s a battle that’s being attacked and stops being a battle, or if it’s an attacking or blocking creature that regenerates (see rule 701.15), stops being a creature, or becomes a battle. A creature that’s removed from combat stops being an attacking, blocking, blocked, and/or unblocked creature. A planeswalker or battle that’s removed from combat stops being attacked

*Emphasis mine*